# Non-EU citizen with residence permit in EU country, travel in EU without visa for studies?

Tags: albanian-citizens

I am a non-EU citizen (Albania), living in Greece with a residence permit, in February 2016 I want to visit Poland for ERASMUS programm studies. Can I go there without a visa and stay there more than 3 months becouse the semester lasts 6 months?

Answer (score 6):

No, in the Schengen area, the length of stay is paramount. If it's under 3 months, you can go there without visa, even for studies. If it's above 3 months, you need a long-stay visa or residence permit from the country you are going to, no matter the purpose.

Answer (score 4):

No. You definitely need a type D visa (national visa) if you want to stay in other Schengen countries for more than 3 months.
I am a citizen of Azerbaijan doing PhD in Germany. As part of the program, I needed to spend 1 year in Poland. Although I had 3 years of residence permit, I still needed to apply for a national visa of Poland.